Solrj with Solr 9.7, SolrClient create nested docs without using InputDocuments?
I see that you can easily create nested documents in solar like this:
https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_11/indexing-nested-documents.html
But there is another API that uses the @Field annotation that I would prefer to use like this:
public class SolrOrderPostDTO {

@Field
public long id;

@Field
public String orderNumber;
@Field
public String orderPo;
@Field
public String customerName;

Then you send such a bean to solr like:
try (Http2SolrClient solr = builder.build();) {
        solr.addBean(dtoBean);
        solr.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    }

But all my fields get created at the same level.   When I add a field like this:
@Field(child = true)
public Collection<InternalNoteDTO> internalNoteDtos = new ArrayList<InternalNoteDTO>();

...all the members of that collection get created at the same level as the root document.   ...has anyone been able to create such a bean with "@Field" type annotation, that will magically create a nested doc simply with SolrClient.add(bean)?
